# GNOME 3 graphics problem on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: unity, gnome, amd-graphics

I installed GNOME 3 on my Ubuntu 11.04 but it doesn't work as well as it must.

Please see the following picture:

[image: GNOME 3 on Ubuntu 11.04]

Comment: i solved it. i remove the active graphic driver and the problem was solved.

Comment: Good to know. Which graphic card are you using?

Comment: If you have an ATI graphic card that's the problem, the're are a lot of users with the same problem, as far as is know there's no solution till know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may installed Gnome 3 wrong. The only things you have to do is the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

sudo aptitude update

sudo aptitude dist-upgrade

sudo aptitude install gnome-shell
```

Comment: i have install it exactly as well as you mentioned, but i have this problem. what should i do?

Comment: You could delete all gnome folders in your user folder: .gnome .gnome3 .gconf .gconfd .metacity which would reset gnome or try to do that: gconftool-2 --recursive-unset that could fix also the problem. Or look if compiz is on and if yes switch to metacity.